# I need to start over with a fresh, ground zero, install of Rails. How do I do that?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, railsapps, learn-ruby-on-rails

Running Mac OS X Mavericks, I have completely jacked up my Rails installation to the point that I am unable to sort out what all is wrong.  I'm working through the [railsapps.org](http://railsapps.github.io/) book on [learning rails](http://learn-rails.com/learn-ruby-on-rails.html) and am simply trying to set up the test environment so I can actually start learning...   Anyway, I'm so messed up now that I really just need to flush it all and start over.  I have reinstalled Rails, and now the default gemset is empty.  I am unable to figure out at this point how to repopulate it with the default gems (uninstalling and reinstalling Rails did not do this for me).

At this point I'm so far down a rabbit hole that I'm unable to orientate myself, so I feel like I need to just resurface and start over from zero fresh.  How would I go about resetting my environment such that I can do this?  I assume I need to uninstall Rails, RVM, etc?

Comment: Which version of OS X? Version 10.9 Mavericks? It is important to know what version you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure you are running Mac OS X Mavericks (10.9).

Start by uninstalling Ruby, for example:

```
$ rvm remove ruby-2.1.1
```

More info is on the [Removing Rubies](https://rvm.io/rubies/removing) page on the RVM site.

Then carefully follow the guide [Install Ruby on Rails - Mac OS X Mavericks](http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-mac.html) to install Ruby 2.1.1 and Rails 4.1.

If things don't look right, for example if RVM is giving error messages, you can escalate by uninstalling RVM itself. This will removes all Ruby installations RVM manages, and everything in ~/.rvm:

```
$ rvm implode
```

Follow the [Install Ruby on Rails - Mac OS X Mavericks](http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-mac.html) to reinstall RVM, Ruby 2.1.1 and Rails. Take notes as you go and if you encounter any difficulties, ask a new Stack Overflow question, supplying the exact error messages and conditions that created the error. Installing Rails is the biggest obstacle to learning Rails, so good luck, and I'm sure you will succeed with the help you find here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, my teammate had this issue on linux box. He had to completely wipe ALL rails installations. Re-download/install rails installer (http://railsinstaller.org/en) for whatever OS you are using. I dont know what IDE you use... but in our case we use Eclipse with aptana. Reinstall that too then link everything back together. Then in your IDE you should have option to make a default project by calling `rails new blog(replace blog with whatever your project name would be)` After which you should have fresh project to work with. Don't forget to do `bundle install`

Comment: All respect to @pirate694 but please do not use railsinstaller.org. First, it installs old versions of everything (Rails 3.2 and Ruby 1.9.3). Second, it installs RVM at the system (not user) level which will make a serious mess. RailsInstaller is no longer maintained for Mac OS X 10.9. Follow the instructions in the guide at [Install Ruby on Rails - Mac OS X Mavericks](http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-mac.html) using RVM for best results.

Comment: Thanks. That's how class is taught so that's the only way I knew